# I can start and stop AVAudioEngine but can not restart

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine

I am using **AVAudioEngine** to make some changes on playing music like changing pitch and gain at some frequencies (equalizer) and get audio levels. It all works now.

When I stop and tried to restart **AVAudioEngine** I faced a problem it does not start as it is supposed to start.

When I only tried start and stop player it is ok but AudioEngine draws some energy it is not good at all.

I start the player and audio engine like this.

Starting

```swift
audioEngine.prepare()
do {
    try audioEngine.start()
} catch {
    print("audioEngine couldn't start because of an error.")
}
audioFilePlayer.play()
```

I stop it like that

```swift
audioFilePlayer.stop()
audioEngine.stop()
```

But then when I tried to restart using the same code I used to start before it shows some erratic behaviors and basically does not start.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I start it like this

```
do {
            try audioEngine.start()
            audioFilePlayer.play()

        } catch {
            
            print("could not start audio engine")
        
        }
```

and pause like this

```
    audioFilePlayer.pause()
    audioEngine.pause()
```

This worked but after pause / restart I hear a glitch sound.